# "holes" in grid layout, Zurb Foundation

Tags: html, css, grid, zurb-foundation

Can anyone tell me why I might have seemingly random "holes" in my grid layout? I'm using Zurb Foundation.

Even though it is a basic grid layout, some columns floats to the right for no apparent reason. It looks like there is an article missing once in a while, but if you look in the markup, you will se that there are no empty divs pushing things around and the div elements seems to have the same classes and styling?

There are no actual items left out - everything from the database is printed, but the holes are "consistent" in terms of where they are relative to the surrounding items, so it seems like it is related to the content, but I can't see anything in the content suggesting that the problem should lie here.

[Link to the site](http://murmuring-mountain-9361.herokuapp.com/)

Answer (score 0):

try adding **min-height** to the divs *medium-6*.

```
.medium-6 {
    width: 50%;
    min-height: 270px;
}
```